# How can I receive the result of the Rapidshare APIs?

Tags: delphi, rapidshare

I want to use the RapidShare API in my project,but I don't know how I can call it then receive the result.

I use Delphi 2009.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you have to do is make a HTTP request and fetch the result.

Try this link to see how it works: [getapicpu_v1](http://api.rapidshare.com/cgi-bin/rsapi.cgi?sub=getapicpu_v1)

Here you can find which calls you can make: http://images.rapidshare.com/apidoc.txt

The code below prints this:

> getapicpu_v1:
>   0,60000
>
> nextuploadserver_v1: 
>   669

FetchHTML() is just a helper function to retrieve the result of an HTTP request. If you use a proxy, it'll automatically use the one that you've configured in Internet explorer.

```
program RapidShareTest;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  SysUtils, WinInet;

function FetchHTML(url:string):AnsiString;
var
  databuffer : array[0..4095] of AnsiChar;
  ResStr : AnsiString;
  hSession, hfile: hInternet;
  dwindex,dwcodelen,dwread,dwNumber:cardinal;
  dwcode : array[1..20] of char;
  res    : pAnsiChar;
  Str    : pAnsiChar;
begin
  ResStr := '';
  if pos('http://',lowercase(url))=0 then
    url := 'http://'+url;

  hSession := InternetOpen('InetURL:/1.0', INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_PRECONFIG,nil, nil, 0);
  try
    if assigned(hsession) then
      begin
        hfile := InternetOpenUrl(hsession,pchar(url),nil,0,INTERNET_FLAG_RELOAD, 0);
        dwIndex  := 0;
        dwCodeLen := 10;
        HttpQueryInfo(hfile, HTTP_QUERY_STATUS_CODE,@dwcode, dwcodeLen, dwIndex);
        res := pAnsiChar(@dwcode);
        dwNumber := sizeof(databuffer)-1;
        while (InternetReadfile(hfile,@databuffer,dwNumber,DwRead)) do
          begin
            if dwRead =0 then
              break;
            databuffer[dwread]:=#0;
            Str := pAnsiChar(@databuffer);
            resStr := resStr + Str;
          end;
        if assigned(hfile) then
          InternetCloseHandle(hfile);
      end;
  finally
    InternetCloseHandle(hsession);
  end;
  Result := resStr;
end;


begin
  Writeln('getapicpu_v1: ');
  WriteLn(FetchHTML('http://api.rapidshare.com/cgi-bin/rsapi.cgi?sub=getapicpu_v1'));
  WriteLn;

  Writeln('nextuploadserver_v1: ');
  WriteLn(FetchHTML('http://api.rapidshare.com/cgi-bin/rsapi.cgi?sub=nextuploadserver_v1'));
  WriteLn;

  ReadLn;

end.
```

Comment: thank you so much .. i try it with idhttp and it works so nice and it save all of this codes .. is that ok ?